# How can I obfuscate Tailwindcss HTML classnames in production?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, obfuscation, tailwind-css

How can I obfuscate the HTML classnames in production when using Tailwindcss? My project uses React.js and CRACO as per tailwind's documentation.

Comment: Maybe this can help you out https://github.com/sndyuk/mangle-css-class-webpack-plugin
Other than that: think about if its really necessary

Comment: Sure, what's the point of hiding that? It's the web after all.

Comment: its useless, whats the point doing that.
tailwindcss is utility based framework & it has huge css properties & classnames.
obfuscating makes building slower & slower as project grows.
so I prefer not to do it.

Comment: I understand if someone was intent on copying the website they could, but at a minimum, I still prefer to minify or obscure the classnames as it does slow-down and deter those not comfortable with coding.

Comment: Pretty sure that the tools that copy a website, do copy the actual final CSS and not all the subclasses.